# Cache line locking

Tags: caching, mips, cpu-architecture

I understand there is a cache line locking instruction in Mips which prevents your data from being ejected from the cache. I am curious as to what happens when you lock down all the cache lines and a new address is read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, the data at the new address is simply read from memory and not saved in the cache. Nothing terrible happens.